# Зачем создавать экземпляр интерфейса?

Tags: c#

Зачем создавать экземпляр интерфейса?

```
public interface IMyInterface { }

class Program
{
    private IMyInterface inter;
}
```

Comment: а с чего Вы взяли что это экземпляр интерфейса, это переменная с интерфейсной ссылкой.

Comment: @Yaroslav А как это может быть использовано?

Comment: Опять-таки для изучения базовых конструкций языка лучше читать [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/index) и [учебные материалы](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.9.php). Этот сайт лучше подходит для конкретных проблем. У интерфейсов много сценариев использования, копировать сюда книги по ООП как-то неоптимально.

Comment: http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/charp_theory/level9/9_2.php

Comment: Как минимум для возможности использовать полиморфизм)
ООП и все прочее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изначальная задача интерфейсов в объектно-ориентированных языках программирования - передавать в наследство классу только свойства и методы. Интерфейс не может реализовать их. Это делают классы, которые наследуют интерфейс.

В Вашем коде показан не экземпляр интерфейса, а Интерфейсная ссылка. **Интерфейсная ссылка** - это переменная, ссылающаяся на метод, реализующий её интерфейс.

**Пример использования интерфейсной ссылки:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace InterfaceExemplar
{
    public interface IMyInterface
    {
        void Function1();
        void Function2();
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task task = new Task();
            IMyInterface inter;
            inter = task;
            inter.Function1();
            inter.Function2();
        }
    }
    class Task : IMyInterface
    {
        public void Function1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First Function");
        }
        public void Function2()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Second Function");
        }
    }
}
```

**Основные фрагменты кода:**

**1. Интерфейс IMyInterface, в котором находятся два метода: Function1 и Function2.**

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void Function1();
    void Function2();
}
```

**2. Класс Task, который наследует интерфейс IMyInterface и реализует все члены данного интерфейса.**

```
class Task : IMyInterface
{
    public void Function1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("First Function");
    }
    public void Function2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Second Function");
    }
}
```

**3. В классе Programm реализуем экземпляр класса Task.Создаём интерфейсную ссылку и вызываем методы интерфейса IMyInterface.**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task task = new Task();
        IMyInterface inter;
        inter = task;
        inter.Function1();
        inter.Function2();
    }
}
```

**Переменной inter доступны только те методы, которые объявлены в ее интерфейсе IMyInterface. Поэтому интерфейсную ссылку нельзя использовать для доступа к любым другим методам, которые не поддерживаются объектом класса, реализующего данный интерфейс.**

**Итог работы программы:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь этот ответ был вам полезен.

Comment: Теперь понятно, спасибо большое за развернутый ответ.

Comment: "Интерфейсная ссылка - это переменная, ссылающаяся на метод, реализующий её интерфейс" - не согласен, причём здесь методы? Это просто обычная переменная, т.к. интерфейс является по сути обычным ссылочным типом. Добавьте это в ответ, т.к. это может ввести в заблуждение.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых: Вы не можете создать экземпляр интерфейса, то есть использовать `new`:

```cs
// так работать не будет
IList list = new IList<object>();
// а так можно
IList list = new List<object>();
```

В приведённом Вами примере в классе `Program` просто объявляется поле с *типом* `IMyInterface`. Сохранить в него можно любой объект/экземпляр, который реализует этот интерфейс.

Теперь, на мой взгляд, самая важная часть вопроса: зачем...
Представьте, что у Вас имеется некий метод, который выводит в консоль текстовое представление каждого элемента `List`:

```cs
private WriteItemsToConsole(List<object> list) {
  foreach(var item in list) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
  }
}
```

В приведённом выше примере используется просто итерация по листу и если в будущем Вам понадобится выводить в консоль не только содержимое `List`, но и к примеру содержимое массива, то при таком подходе придётся создавать перегруженный метод, который будет принимать параметром `Array`. Но нам в действительности не важно какой тип имеет передаваемый параметр, самое главное, чтоб он поддерживал нашу инструкцию `foreach`. Как раз это предоставляет интерфейс `IEnumerable`. Здесь и можно применить интерфейс, как тип параметра и тогда метод сможет печатать в консоль любые объекты/экземпляры, которые [реализуют интерфейс](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable?view=netframework-4.7.2) `IEnumerable`:

```cs
private WriteItemsToConsole(IEnumerable<object> ienum) {
  foreach(var item in ienum) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
  }
}
```

---

Ещё пример. Представьте, что Вы определяете следующие классы:

```cs
public class Person {
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
public class Product {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
public class Contract {
  public Guid ContractId { get; set; }
  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Не смотря на то, что они относятся к разным сущностям, все они имеют одно одинаковое свойство - `IsDeleted`, которое указывает на то, что сущность была логически удалена и не должна включаться в операции выборки из БД (по-моему такой подход называется "мягким удалением"). Если всё оставить так как есть, то Вы столкнётесь с проблемами при работе со свойством `IsDeleted`, так как нет никакого интерфейса (читай соглашения) об этом свойстве, оно не объявлено в каком-либо общем для них всех родительском классе и Вам придётся явно указывать тип (`Person`, `Product`, etc.). Здесь тоже можно (скорее всего нужно) использовать интерфейс:

```cs
public interface ISoftDelete {
  bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
public class Person : ISoftDelete {
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
public class Product : ISoftDelete {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Теперь при необходимости доступа к свойству `IsDeleted` Вам не нужно указывать все возможные варианты, а достаточно указать тип `ISoftDelete` и Вы получите доступ к свойству `IsDeleted` вне зависимости от того в каком типе оно определено.

Другими словами: интерфейс - это некое соглашение с помощью которого Вы можете получать доступ к переменным и методам определённых в интерфейсе вне зависимости от типа, в котором они были объявлены.